# How to clear screen using node/npm blessed (curses-like library)

Tags: node.js

I am using node/npm blessed to create a screen to monitor a particular application and I want the monitor tool to look/act like linux top.  The problem I have, which I think is relatively simple (but I cant find the answer anywhere), is to have blessed clear the screen at startup as well as at particular points based upon user input.

Right now I can use blessed to paint the screen properly (sample program below), but the problem is I need the screen to be cleared at startup (right now the first line of output just appends right after you start up the program):

```
var blessed = require('blessed');

var screen = blessed.screen(),
    body = blessed.box({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      tags: true
    });

var items = [];

screen.append(body);

screen.key(['escape', 'q', 'C-c'], function(ch, key) {
  return process.exit(0);
});

function log(text) {
  items.push(text);

  var MAX = 10;
  if( items.length > MAX+1 ){
    items.shift();
  }

  for (var i=1; i<MAX; i++){
    body.setLine(i, items[i]);
  }
  screen.render();

}

function status(text) {
  body.setLine(0, text );
  screen.render();
}

var counter = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  status((new Date()).toISOString());
  log('Line number: ' + (counter++));
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, the solution to this question is provided below, and is very simple.  To clear the screen, issue the following code at the start of the program:

```
screen.render();
```

The sample program that I referenced in the original post can be modified as follows and now works:

```
var blessed = require('blessed');

var screen = blessed.screen(),
    body = blessed.box({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      tags: true
    });

// The following line clears the screen
screen.render();
:
:
```